# Class Extending FirebaseMessagingService not working inside Android Library

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I created an Android Library to implement FCM to use in my internal projects, where I implement a class to extend FirebaseMessagingService (`.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService` ) and another one to extend FirebaseInstanceIdService (`.services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService`).

I defined this in my AndroidManifest.xml inside the library as below:

```
<!-- [START firebase_service] -->
<service
    android:name=".services.MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_service] -->
<!-- [START firebase_iid_service] -->
<service android:name=".services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
<!-- [END firebase_iid_service] -->
```

When I included all the library source code as a module in my App, everything worked well, but when I included only the AAR generated, I received this error when I run my application:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.lib.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.lib.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2380)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.lib.services.MyFirebaseMessagingService
  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2377)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:138) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1286) 
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4905) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790) 
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557) 
  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The service com.example.lib.services.MyFirebaseInstanceIDService works correctly.

What I need to do with AAR generated library to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For FCM follow this step : 
1 - in main Build.gradle (not in app folder) add this line :

```
buildscript {
// ...
dependencies {
    // ...
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
}
```

2- in app/build.gradle add this line :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.8.0'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // the latest Google Repository in the Android SDK manager
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Note : "Android Support Repository" in you SDk most be updated .
Hope this help

Comment: Thanks a lot @soheil-tayyeb, works well right now. I thought that if I already had `com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0` included in library dependencies, I didn't need to include in app dependencies.

Comment: I tried with the same Build.gradle settings, but still face the same issues.

Comment: I applied it and it didn't help :(

Answer (score -1):

click on Build - > Clean then install & run the app